# Parse JSON :Nested Objects in Android

Tags: android, json

I am pretty new to Android.I am trying to parse a JSON url. But I am getting following error "Json parsing error: No value for unofficial-summary".
Here is the response that I am getting.

Response from url: {"success":true,"data":{"summary":{"total":15616130,"confirmedCasesIndian":15616082,"confirmedCasesForeign":48,"discharged":13276039,"deaths":182553,"confirmedButLocationUnidentified":0},"unofficial-summary":[{"source":"covid19india.org","total":7945975,"recovered":7198877,"deaths":119538,"active":626192}],"regional":[{"loc":"Andaman and Nicobar Islands","confirmedCasesIndian":5466,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":5243,"deaths":64,"totalConfirmed":5466},{"loc":"Andhra Pradesh","confirmedCasesIndian":976987,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":915626,"deaths":7472,"totalConfirmed":976987},{"loc":"Arunachal Pradesh","confirmedCasesIndian":17113,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":16835,"deaths":56,"totalConfirmed":17113},{"loc":"Assam","confirmedCasesIndian":227473,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":217296,"deaths":1145,"totalConfirmed":227473},{"loc":"Bihar","confirmedCasesIndian":342059,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":283863,"deaths":1841,"totalConfirmed":342059},{"loc":"Chandigarh","confirmedCasesIndian":35148,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":30768,"deaths":421,"totalConfirmed":35148},{"loc":"Chhattisgarh","confirmedCasesIndian":574299,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":442337,"deaths":6274,"totalConfirmed":574299},{"loc":"Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu","confirmedCasesIndian":5422,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":4047,"deaths":4,"totalConfirmed":5422},{"loc":"Delhi","confirmedCasesIndian":905540,"confirmedCasesForeign":1,"discharged":807328,"deaths":12638,"totalConfirmed":905541},{"loc":"Goa","confirmedCasesIndian":69311,"confirmedCasesForeign":1,"discharged":60145,"deaths":926,"totalConfirmed":69312},{"loc":"Gujarat","confirmedCasesIndian":428177,"confirmedCasesForeign":1,"discharged":346063,"deaths":5615,"totalConfirmed":428178},{"loc":"Haryana","confirmedCasesIndian":371610,"confirmedCasesForeign":14,"discharged":318369,"deaths":3483,"totalConfirmed":371624},{"loc":"Himachal Pradesh","confirmedCasesIndian":79410,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":68164,"deaths":1219,"totalConfirmed":79410},{"loc":"Jammu and Kashmir","confirmedCasesIndian":150238,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":134697,"deaths":2071,"totalConfirmed":150238},{"loc":"Jharkhand","confirmedCasesIndian":172315,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":137590,"deaths":1547,"totalConfirmed":172315},{"loc":"Karnataka","confirmedCasesIndian":1198644,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":1025821,"deaths":13646,"totalConfirmed":1198644},{"loc":"Kerala","confirmedCasesIndian":1272637,"confirmedCasesForeign":8,"discharged":1148671,"deaths":4978,"totalConfirmed":1272645},{"loc":"Ladakh","confirmedCasesIndian":12556,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":10610,"deaths":134,"totalConfirmed":12556},{"loc":"Lakshadweep","confirmedCasesIndian":1335,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":817,"deaths":1,"totalConfirmed":1335},{"loc":"Madhya Pradesh","confirmedCasesIndian":433704,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":350720,"deaths":4713,"totalConfirmed":433704},{"loc":"Maharashtra","confirmedCasesIndian":3960356,"confirmedCasesForeign":3,"discharged":3213464,"deaths":61343,"totalConfirmed":3960359},{"loc":"Manipur","confirmedCasesIndian":29869,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":29106,"deaths":378,"totalConfirmed":29869},{"loc":"Meghalaya","confirmedCasesIndian":15116,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":14105,"deaths":154,"totalConfirmed":15116},{"loc":"Mizoram","confirmedCasesIndian":5085,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":4569,"deaths":12,"totalConfirmed":5085},{"loc":"Nagaland","confirmedCasesIndian":12650,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":12299,"deaths":94,"totalConfirmed":12650},{"loc":"Odisha","confirmedCasesIndian":377464,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":349377,"deaths":1953,"totalConfirmed":377464},{"loc":"Puducherry","confirmedCasesIndian":48974,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":43184,"deaths":717,"totalConfirmed":48974},{"loc":"Punjab","confirmedCasesIndian":309316,"confirmedCasesForeign":0,"discharged":264562,"deaths":8045,"t

What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.sudarshan.jsonparse2;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Json Data is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONObject c  = jsonObj.getJSONArray("unofficial-summary").getJSONObject(0);
                    String source = c.getString("source");
                        int total = c.getInt("total");
                        int recovered = c.getInt("recovered");
                        int deaths = c.getInt("deaths");
                        int active = c.getInt("active");


                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> summary = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        summary.put("source", "source: "+source);
                        summary.put("total", "total:" +String.valueOf(total));
                        summary.put("recovered", "recovered" +String.valueOf(recovered));
                        summary.put("deaths", "deaths" + String.valueOf(deaths));
                        summary.put("active", "active" + String.valueOf(active));

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(summary);

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "source","total","recovered","deaths","active"},
                    new int[]{R.id.source, R.id.total,R.id.recovered,R.id.deaths,R.id.active});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use gson library for json deserialization/serialization - https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: But i dont wantbto convert json to java object and vice versa. I want to parse json and extract information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json is like

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "summary": {
        //...
    },
    "unofficial-summary": [
    {
        //...
    }]
    }
}
```

Shoud get data first:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String url = "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/stats/latest";
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            // Add: 2021/4/26 add get data first 
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String data = jsonObj.getString("data");
            Log.w(TAG, "doInBackground: " + data);
            // Getting JSON Array node
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(data).getJSONArray("unofficial-summary").getJSONObject(0);
            String source = c.getString("source");
            int total = c.getInt("total");
            int recovered = c.getInt("recovered");
            int deaths = c.getInt("deaths");
            int active = c.getInt("active");
            // tmp hash map for single contact
            HashMap<String, String> summary = new HashMap<>();
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            summary.put("source", "source: " + source);
            summary.put("total", "total:" + String.valueOf(total));
            summary.put("recovered", "recovered" + String.valueOf(recovered));
            summary.put("deaths", "deaths" + String.valueOf(deaths));
            summary.put("active", "active" + String.valueOf(active));
            // adding contact to contact list
            contactList.add(summary);
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
           //...
        }
    } else {
       //...
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Sorry couldnt exactly comprehend what you mean to say.Your code and mine look exactly the same.

Comment: hi@Sudarshan Taparia,i updated some code in your code,check here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZjQ0.png